# Fail to call destructor of other class C++

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

So I have this code, and when I run it, I got a run time error when class B is trying to call its destructor. The destructor of class A seems fine. I wonder what's wrong with this code. Thanks for helping.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class A{
    public:
        //Constructor
        A(int N){
            this->N = N;
            array = new int[N];
        }

        //Copy Constructor
        A(const A& A1){
            this->N = A1.N;

            //Create new array with exact size
            this->array = new int[N];

            //Copy element
            for(int i=0; i<N; i++){
                this->array[i]= A1.array[i];
            }
        }

        ~A(){
            delete [] array;
            cout<<"Success"<<endl;
        }

        int N;
        int* array;
};

class B{
    public:
        B(const A& array1){
            array = new A(array1);
        }

        ~B(){
            delete [] array;
        }

        A* array;
};

using namespace std;

int main(){
    A matrix1(10);
    B testing(matrix1);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Class `B` is more unsafe than `A` . In the presented code you allocate with `new` but deallocate with `delete[]`. Use `std::vector` instead of raw pointers and manual memory management.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In `B::~B()`, you call `delete[]` on `B::array` after allocating it via `new` in `B::B(const A&)`.

This is illegal: You must always pair `new` with `delete` and `new[]` with `delete[]`.

Answer (score 1):

you can't use the `delete []` when you don't create an array of elements, your destructor must be like:

```
~B(){
        delete  array;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `[]` when you delete the allocated memory in b because you allocated for just one element and the `[]` makes the compiler assumes that you are deleting an array allocated memory.